# Get access to street data in iOS

Tags: ios, algorithm, google-maps, openstreetmap

I have a graph G with n nodes. The graph is embedded in 2D space (so that there are well-defined angles and distances between each pair of nodes). Some nodes might be connected with edges to other nodes. Given a location L, this graph needs to be laid out on top of a map close to L, such that each node becomes a marker on a map, and such that there is a walkable path between each pair of connected of nodes. Since this will not be possible most of the time, I will allow the graph to be scaled/rotated and I will alow the distances and angles between nodes to be flexible within a certain range.

In order for me to write this specific algorithm, I would need to have some specific information about the streets near L. Does anybody know to get street data as a graph structure (so that I can get walkable paths)? I know the Google Maps API allows you to get directions between two points but I'm sure I cannot just keep getting directions without incurring any cost.

**Edit: I've been reading a bit about OpenStreetMap API. It looks like this could be interesting. Maybe people can comment on this as well.**

Comment: I have used this geonames service based on OpenStreetMap for a similar task if it can be of some help: http://www.geonames.org/maps/osm-reverse-geocoder.html#findNearbyStreetsOSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TIGER datasets offer a shape/line file for the USA, free. Lots of options including roads. https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html

Comment: thanks, that looks very helpful. i will post back here if i end up using it in my project.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out these sites for osm and open gis data.

OpenStreetMap Extracts, [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/)

OpenStreetMap derived data, [here](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data)

GIS Datasets, [here](http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/)

in addition to these;

Planet.osm/diffs [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm)

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Mostly this data is in different formats which you will have to convert your self but mostly its returned in XML format or in some form of GeoJson